# How to get original text body in WSO2 mediation in case of HL7?

Tags: soap, wso2, hl7, wso2-esb

I've implemented a simple API service in WSO2 EI. The Input endpoint is configured to accept 'application/edi-hl7' essentially to read HL7 message. I perform certain transformations on the message and then need to respond with JSON. So, as part of the response JSON payload I also want to have original HL7 message sent as request payload and that too in original shape (not XML / JSON formatted).
Say my input is,

> MSH|^~\&|ULTRA_V3.1|LAV|Web Portal|Web Portal|201810030949||ORU^R01|279857418|P|2.3.1|||AL|AL|AU
>   PID||3914950|21710425491^^^AUSHIC^MC~111111^^^^UR~5548391^^^^ULTRAREL||KAY^BRUCE^^^||19630604|M|||11 NJUONA AVE^^BAIURE BAY^WSN^2000||^^^^^^0243333323||||||21710425491
>   PV1||O|CSLI^KINUYMBER|||||214082JL^KOPRA^MARUTI^^KAYBB^DR
>   ORC|RE||18-15768981-000-0||R
>   OBR|1||18-15768981-000-0|000^PENDING^ULTRA^LAVLEI||20180914|201810030805|||CSKI||||201810030949||214082JL^KOPRA^MARUTI^^KAYBB^DR||TFT-0^GLU-0^CRP-0^RDA-0^MBA-0^LIP-0^FBE-0||683131368452|LAV^false|201810030949||LAB|I||^^^20180914|

And sample output is,

```
{"message": "MSH|^~\&|.....", "Otherkeys": "someVal"}
```

As part of `message`, I want original message as is and not SOAP body.
P.S. I need to remove `\n\r` available at the end of each line.
The main question is how can get the original message in original shape in the mediation flow.

Comment: Could you show us your sequence's XML?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample API. Hope It helps.
[Screenshot of the result](https://yadi.sk/i/sg-dSbOBAzN8Lw)
Just put payloadFactory Mediator in appropriate place in your Sequence.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" context="/Test">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/testHL">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"message": "$1", "Otherkeys": "someVal"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/*[1]"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the expression string that you mentioned in an argument?

Comment: It didn't work for me as I'm reading the message as 'application/edi-hl7'. My request content-type is set to application/edi-hl7.

Comment: @AashishP, If you show me your medation, I could help better.

Comment: Could You put Log mediator before with level="full" and bring the result here? As for $body/*[1], that just means - take the body of the message context, and get the first child of it.